# How to dynamically create '&' filters of varying length for pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Purpose of code:

Based upon the inputs (`test_tuple` & `params`), which can be of varying length, from the main DataFrame (`df`), generate a filtered DataFrame (`filtered_df`).  There are potentially hundreds of filter combinations.

Reason for post:

Everything here works to produce the expected output. That being said, I don't like the implementation method of Solution 1, where a dummy DataFrame object is created in the `dict`, which the loop successively filters and updates.  Solution 1 seems a little kludged, but I need some guidance implementing something more succinct.

Request:

Is there a way to use `filter_t` as shown in Solution 2?

`filter_t` is formatted correctly, but is a string.  Is there a way to produce `filter_t` so it can be used as shown?

Input Example:

```
test_tuple = [('Serial Number', [12345]),
              ('Test Points', ['TestpointA', 'TestpointC']),
              ('Voltage_1', [3.0, 3.3, 3.6, 0.0]),
              ('Temperature Setpoint', [0, 60]),
              ('Slew_1', [200, 400, 800, 1600, 3200, 6400])]
params = ['sn', 'tp', 'v1', 'temp', 'slew']
```

Code:

```
for i in itertools.product(*[b for _, b in test_tuple]):
     print('\n'.join(f'{a}:{b}' for a, b in zip(params, i)))
     name_params = '_'.join(f'{b}{a}' for a, b in zip(params, i)) 
     filter_t = ' & '.join(f'(self.df["{c[0]}"] == {b})' for b, c in zip(i, test_tuple))
     print(f'filter_t: {filter_t}')
     filter_l = [(c[0], b) for b, c in zip(i, test_tuple)]
```

Format of filter_t as as a string:

```
filter_t: (self.df["Test Points"] == 3P3V) & (self.df["Slew_1"] == 5000)
filter_t: (self.df["Serial Number"] == 2450) & (self.df["Test Points"] == 3P3V) & (self.df["Voltage_1"] == 11.6) & (self.df["Temperature Setpoint"] == 25.0) & (self.df["Slew_1"] == 5000)
```

Format of filter_l:

```
filter_l: [('Test Points', '3P3V_Edge'), ('Slew_1', 200)]
filter_l: [('Serial Number', 1234), ('Test Points', '3P3V'), ('Voltage_1', 11.6), ('Temperature Setpoint', 25.0), ('Slew_1', 200)]
```

Solution 1 - Works without issue:

```
filtered_df = {1: df}
for x in filter_l:
     filtered_df[1] = (filtered_df[1].loc[(filtered_df[1][f'{x[0]}'] == x[1])])
```

Solution 2 - Possible?:

```
df_filter = self.df.loc[filter_t]
```

Filter Example:

```
df_filter = self.df.loc[(self.df['Serial Number'] == 1234) &
                        (self.df['Test Points'] == '3P3V') &
                        (self.df['Voltage_1'] == 11.6) &
                        (self.df['Temperature Setpoint'] == 25.0) &
                        (self.df['Slew'] == 200)]
```

Final Solution @John Zwinck - Thx:

```
filter_t = ' & '.join(f'{c[0]} == "{b}"' for b, c in zip(i, test_tuple))
filtered_df = df.loc[df.eval(filter_t)]

print(f'filter_t: {filter_t}')
>>> filter_t: Test_Points == "3P3V" & Slew_1 == "5000"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can install `numexpr`, I suggest trying [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas.DataFrame.query) for this.

First you'll need to replace spaces with underscores (or with nothing) in your column names.  Then, build and use a filter string like this:

```
filter_str = 'Serial_Number == 2450 and Test_Points == "3P3V" and Voltage_1 == 11.6'
df_filter = df.query(filter_str)
```

If you have `numexpr` installed, this may be the fastest solution.

Alternatively, build a list of masks and then combine them.  This is similar to but better than your Solution 1:

```
masks = [df[x[0]] == x[1] for x in filter_l] # list of bool arrays
filtered_df = df[np.logical_and.reduce(masks)] # combine and apply masks
```